# Runing os.system (for command line) from Task Scheduler (in Windows) or SQL Server Agent

Tags: python

I am trying to run this particular command line from Task Scheduler or SQL Server Agent.

So, the basic command line is like this:

```
SQBConverter "C:\Full_Pubs.sbq" "C:\Full_Pubs.bak" "password"
```

SQBConverter is a third party's (RedGate's) exe file that converts files from SQB format to BAK format. This command works when it gets run from a Python editor or using command line directly.

On my Python code, I have these lines:

```
for f in glob.glob(r'Z:\\Test\\*.SQB'):  
    os.system( f'SQBConverter "{f}" "{f[:-4]}.bak" {password}' )
```

The issue is, when I run the Python code from an editor manually, there is no issue.
But, when I try to run this Python code from Task Scheduler or SQL Server Agent, it does not run this part of code.

I am thinking that issue is because it runs the command line (maybe needs Admin right?).
Should I run other better way or use other library (other than **os**) to run the command line?

Comment: Does z is a real hard disk? We often use this letter for a network disk and Task scheduler doesn't have access to it. If I am right, you should use the real address of this disk.

Comment: Otherwise, you can try to run your task with option "run only when user is logged on" thus you will see the command prompt and the error

Comment: @DonKnacki How do I see the messages shown on the Command prompts? It just disappeared really quick.

Comment: You can call your script in a batch file and use `pause` just after.

Comment: @DonKnacki  I did, but the messages that I wanted to see appeared earlier and only message that I see is the last line. So first few lines of message are not shown at the end.

Comment: Maybe you can add a waiting time with `time.sleep`. I think you need to add a try except and put the waiting time in the except part

Comment: @DonKnacki Ok. That helped. So it says "'SQBConverter' is not recognized as an internal or external command". I am curious why it works when python code is run manually, but it does not run when it is used by Task Scheduler.

Comment: What about using absolute path to run SQBConverter?

Comment: @DonKnacki. Yes, that is what I am trying to find out. How do I express in the code if exe file is located in C:\Test\ ? Is it  os.system( 'C:\\Test\\SQBConverter "{f}" "{f[:-4]}.bak" {password}' )

Comment: Nearly yes, you should add extension also `os.system( 'C:\\Test\\SQBConverter.exe "{f}" "{f[:-4]}.bak" {password}' )`

Comment: @DonKnacki It worked finally. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share the solution here: after some investigation, it appears that SQBConverter was not recognized.

Solution is to use absolute path

```
os.system( 'C:\\Test\\SQBConverter.exe "{f}" "{f[:-4]}.bak" {password}' )
```

Adding  SQBConverter path to system path should also fix the problem