# Task scheduler not run task with cmd prompt running background

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to run a particular program that uses `os.system` to run cmd commands from Task Scheduler.

```
os.system('"C:\\Program Files\\BlueStacks_nxt\\HD-Player.exe" --instance Nougat32')
os.system('cmd /c "adb start-server"')
```

The code works perfectly when I run from my IDE. However, whenever I try to run the py file or exported exe file, the program is not able to start BlueStack nor adb server. The exe file also works fine when I just run the exe file directly.

I first thought it might be some error and used try/catch phrase to log the exception but no exceptions were raised.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525349/runing-os-system-for-command-line-from-task-scheduler-in-windows-or-sql-serv#comment119353766_67525349) I found a way to display cmd prompt while the task is running. When I changed the setting to "run only when user is logged on", cmd prompt poped up and the `os.system` worked.

**So my question is why does the `os.system` not work when cmd prompt is running from background but does when cmd prompt is displayed?** I was able to check that the cmd was running properly in the background through Task Manager and both of the times the privilege were all set to highest.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the `os.system` does work, but the process fails to run for some reason.

Can you try to save the output of the terminal to a file and see if there is any output?
To do this you can your command with `subprocess.Popen` which gives you the stout and stderr of the command.